# How to choose that which ORM would be feasible for or Application? e.g if we are using Linq then why not hibernate

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql, orm, linq-to-entities

How to choose that which ORM would be feasible for a web Application? e.g if we are using Linq then why not nhibernate? and Which one is better and why

Comment: There's loads of posts on this, check out the related questions found on the right hand side of this page, near the bottom...

Comment: possible duplicate of [nhibernate, entity framework, active records or linq2sql ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every ORM that claims linq support, supports linq to a degree, however the completeness of the implementations vary greatly, sometimes because of the way the ORM is implemented, sometimes because of the quality of the Linq implementation.

Even the Linq implementations between Linq to Sql and Entity Framework v4 vary greatly, if you then look at NHibernate's or LlblGenPro's implementations you will find there are queries that are possible in sql that each doesn't support in the same way, if at all, or that the support with different levels of efficiency.

You really need to evaluate the particular ORM's Linq implementation against the type of data retrieval you tend/want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot would depend on the application you are building.

On the other hand, NHibernate is very powerful and can be customized to do just about anything. We recently dumped our old ORM and moved to NHibernate because we just couldn't do what we needed to do without it.

Comment: Like? I'm interested to know as I'm soon facing the same criteria research.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq with nHibernate. But take the most popular ORM. The one the most developers use.

It will be easier to find a developers to maintain and enhance the project and it will be easier to find solutions to your problems on Google.

I'm still using nHibernate but new versions of Entity Framework look promising.

I will switch when Entity Framework will become as powerful as nHibernate.